# how can i pass my div id in angular once i click the div

Tags: angular

new to angular

I have 3 div's i need to give them each an ID once i click i need to pass the divs id as well:

```
<div (click)="ToBank(e)"></div>
 <div (click)="ToBank(e)"></div>
 <div (click)="ToBank(e)"></div>


ToBank(e){

 ///i need to get which is clicked?
    }
```

i dont know how can i give name to each div that i can get it in my function,i know in javascript we have getElementByID but here whats the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the element you've clicked on using `event.target`

In your case.

```js
ToBank(e){
    let target = e.target;
    }
```

There are more details about events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: but should i give id attribute to my div?

Comment: @masali you don't HAVE to give an ID if you don't want/ need to.

Comment: but e.target returns diffrent values for diffrent divs?

Comment: So when you've clicked the element, the JS has access to that specific DOM element. After clicking do you want to add a class / id / value to that element?

Answer (score 1):

In angular you don't need to use ids, instead you can use [Template Variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variables).

These are created has follows:

```html
<div #divOne (click)="ToBank(e)"></div>
<div #divTwo (click)="ToBank(e)"></div>
<div #divThree (click)="ToBank(e)"></div>
```

Then you can pass the variable directly:

```html
<div #divOne (click)="ToBank(e, divOne)"></div>
<div #divTwo (click)="ToBank(e, divTwo)"></div>
<div #divThree (click)="ToBank(e, divThree)"></div>
```

If you want to access them in your component directly, you can use the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator to do so. Keep in mind that they will only be available in the **AfterViewInit** lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) to your method using the `$event` keyword

```html
<div (click)="ToBank($event)"></div>
```

and then use it to set the div's id.

```js
ToBank(event) {
  event.target.id = 'nyDiv';
}
```

As far as I understand, you also want to pass the ids to the `ToBank()` method. You can do it by adding a second parameter

```js
ToBank(event, id) {
  event.target.id = id;
}
```

and then providing the ids in the second arguments.

```html
<div (click)="ToBank($event, 'id1')"></div>
<div (click)="ToBank($event, 'id2')"></div>
<div (click)="ToBank($event, 'id3')"></div>
```

---

Using [template variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variables), you can pass the DOM element without having to pass the entire Event object.

```html
<div #divOne (click)="ToBank(divOne, 'id1')"></div>
<div #divTwo (click)="ToBank(divTwo, 'id2')"></div>
<div #divThree (click)="ToBank(divThree, 'id3')"></div>
```

```js
ToBank(element, id) {
  element.id = id;
}
```

---

Another approach is to store the current ids in a property

```html
<div id="{{ ids[0] }}" (click)="ToBank(0, 'id1')"></div>
<div id="{{ ids[1] }}" (click)="ToBank(1, 'id2')"></div>
<div id="{{ ids[2] }}" (click)="ToBank(2, 'id3')"></div>
```

```js
ids = ['', '', '']; // no ids at first

ToBank(arrayIndex, id) {
  this.ids[arrayIndex] = id;
}
```

or make them depend on a certain property using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```html
<div id="{{ conditions[0] ? 'id1' : '' }}" (click)="ToBank(0)"></div>
<div id="{{ conditions[1] ? 'id2' : '' }}" (click)="ToBank(1)"></div>
<div id="{{ conditions[2] ? 'id3' : '' }}" (click)="ToBank(2)"></div>
```

```js
conditions = [false, false, false]; // no ids at first

ToBank(arrayIndex) {
  this.conditions[arrayIndex] = true;
}
```

---

Note that you normally do not need to use `getElementById()` and alike in Angular. Setting the id only really makes sense if you have some styles for it, but in that case, a class is probably better.